# How to fail OIM Role Provisioning on the basis of certain condition from event handler?

Tags: exception, role, oim

I have a event handler which is working fine and gets executed on role assign and revoke.

Now, I want to raise exception and stop the execution of Role provisioning on certain condition.

Even though I am throwing exception Role is getting provisioned and revoked, and not producing any error on UI.

PS: This role provisioning and deprovisioning is done manually via OIM GUI.

Comment: I haven't tried this except in an explicitly called process task, instead of throwing the exception can you create a error message in the error message definition table(design console) and use oim api's to call it?

Comment: Another way could be to add the event handler to be called when an item is added to the cart and flag the role before the request is even made.  Something similar to http://fusionsecurity.blogspot.com/2012/09/oim-11g-r2-catalog-customization-example.html  That way when the role doesn't get the 200 response you are looking for, it doesn't allow it to be requested in the first place

Comment: can you explain in more detail about your process task approach, as we are provisioning role where we can use process task?

Comment: So i have 2 lines of thought on that.  The process task i created, uses an adapter, which calls a utility task 'Handle Errors'  and I defined an error there.  This prevented the process task from performing any actions.  Like you said, a role has been assigned to a user and is being added to them.  This process task wouldn't really have a good time to be called. BUT if you called the webservice before the role was assigned(say in the cart)  you would be able to prevent it from ever being requested.

Comment: The other thought, is that a role contains access policies which in turn provision accounts/access to users.  You could add a process task inside of the process form for the target system  that the event handler is protecting.  In the create or grant process tasks you could add an adapter that calls the webservice and use the response to determine if the access has been completed or rejected